# Rails + Rspec: test fails due to Javascript 'unsafe-eval' in page with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, selenium, vue.js, capybara

I am trying to run a simple test that just fills out a form and submits, using RSpec, Capybara and Chromedriver. However, the Javascript on the page fails to compile properly so the form can't fully render.

After lots of troubleshooting, I narrowed down the problem to some Vue.js code which determines whether a menu is open or closed:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#dashboard-topbar',
  data: {
    showDropdown: false
  }
})
```

The menu basically just checks whether `showDropdown` is true or false in order to toggle:

```
transition name="fade"
  #dropdown_box(v-show="showDropdown" v-cloak)
    ul
      li Some item 1
      li Some item 2

= link_to fa_icon('chevron-down'), '#', '@blur': 'showDropdown=false', '@click': 'showDropdown=true'
```

I checked Chrome as it was running this test and get the following error:

[image: Chrome fails to render the JS on the page because 'unsafe-eval' is not allowed]

In other words, it seems Chrome doesn't like that `v-show="showDropdown"`.

My `config/initializers/content_security_policy.rb` file is as follows:

```
Rails.application.config.content_security_policy do |policy|
  if Rails.env.development?
    policy.script_src :self, :https, :unsafe_eval
  else
    policy.script_src :self, :https
  end
end
```

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Package versions:

```
rails 6.0.2.1
capybara 3.30.0
capybara-selenium 0.0.6
webdrivers 4.2.0
selenium-webdriver 3.142.7
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like this is an issue. [Someone has made it work by losening the security policy for production as well as development](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/1900#issuecomment-544134822), which is not the best idea, but if it works it might lead to finding a more proper solution.

Comment: Glad to see I'm not alone :) Thanks for the link, I asked there too.